# Get RichTextBox from DataGrid when cells are RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I override my DataGrid to use RichTextBox as DataGridTemplateColumn.
Now in code behind I want to have access to these RichTexBoxes from the grid.
For example I want to get the RichTextBox of row 10 column 1.
How can I do that?

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="First Language" IsReadOnly="False" Width="*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              RichTextBox>
                   <FlowDocument IsOptimalParagraphEnabled="True" IsHyphenationEnabled="True">
                     <Paragraph FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="14 ">
                           <Run Text="{Binding Path=First ,Mode=TwoWay , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                      </Paragraph>
                   </FlowDocument>
              </RichTextBox>
          </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

UPDATE:

with the code I find below I was able to get DataGridCell, but casting the the content as RichTextBox gives me null. Any ideas?

https://svgvijay.blogspot.de/2013/01/how-to-get-datagrid-cell-in-wpf.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int row = 0;
int column = 0;
DataGridCell cell = Datagrid.GetCell(dataGrid, row, column);
ContentPresenter cp = cell.Content as ContentPresenter;
if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(cp) > 0)
{
    RichTextBox rtb = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(cp, 0) as RichTextBox;
}
```